# How to get rid of the gaps on the left and right of a UISlider

Tags: ios5, uislider

I created a UISlider with custom images using setMinimumTrackImage and setMaximumTrackImage.
In the image below I have set the background of UISlider to red so you can see that there is still a little gap on the left and right end of the slider.

How can I get rid of those gaps?

[image: custom uislider]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this issue by subclassing UISlider and overriding trackRectForBounds: method.

```
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds
{
    CGRect result = [super trackRectForBounds:bounds];
    result.origin.x = 0;
    result.size.width = bounds.size.width;
    return result;
}
```